# How to save a DataFrame to excel with caption in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to set a caption for my DataFrame and export it to excel but when I check the excel workbook the caption is not reflected.

```js
import pandas as pd

data={'Name':['Karan','Rohit','Sahil','Aryan'],'Age':[23,22,21,24]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df.style.set_caption("This is caption").hide(axis='index').to_excel("output.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Can anyone please help me to export the DataFrame with caption to xlsx?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write on the first row, you can use:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', index=False, startrow=1)
    ws = writer.book.get_worksheet_by_name('Data')
    ws.write('A1', 'This is a caption')
```

[image]